# How to make a thread wait for others?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading

So my task is to make thread number 14 not end until there are 5 other threads running (including thread number 14). My strategy is to use conditional variables to pause the thread. When 5 threads are "loaded", this means when thread_count is at 5, I'll release the thread. This is what I've come up with:

```
typedef struct {
    int i;
    pthread_cond_t *cond;
    pthread_mutex_t *lock;
}thP2_struct;

int thread_count = 1;
int has_T14_started = 0;
int release_T14 = 0;

void *P2_thread_function(void *arg)
{
    thP2_struct *s = (thP2_struct *) arg;

    if (s->i == 14){
        pthread_mutex_lock(s->lock);
        has_T14_started = 1;
        while(release_T14)
            pthread_cond_wait(s->cond, s->lock);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(s->lock);
    }
    else {
        if (has_T14_started){
            pthread_mutex_lock(s->lock);
            thread_count++;
            if (thread_count == 5){
                release_T14 = 1;
                pthread_cond_signal(s->cond);
                has_T14_started = 0;
            }
            pthread_mutex_unlock(s->lock);
        }

    } 

    return NULL;
}

void function(){

    pthread_cond_t cond = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
    pthread_mutex_t lock = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
    pthread_t tid[40];
    thP2_struct data[40];

    for(int i = 0; i < 40; i++){
        data[i].i = i + 1;
        data[i].cond = &cond;
        data[i].lock = &lock;
        pthread_create(&tid[i], NULL, P2_thread_function, &data[i]);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 40; i++){
        pthread_join(tid[i], NULL);
    }

    pthread_cond_destroy(&cond);
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&lock);
}
```

It's not working how I expect. What might be the problem?

Comment: The term is *condition variable* not condition*al* variable.

Comment: In what way is your program misbehaving?

Comment: @JohnBollinger Well thread 14 terminates even when for example only 2 or 3 threads are running. I want 5 threads to be running at the same time (including thread 14), then thread 14 is allowed to end

Comment: How many times is thread 14 going to repeat that while loop where it waits on the condition variable?

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious problem is the condition on your wait loop:

> ```
>         while(release_T14)
> ```

The sense of the condition is reversed: you want to wait on the CV in the event that thread 14 has *not* been released.  Otherwise T14 should be clear to proceed.

There are additional issues surrounding the behavior of the other threads, too.  In particular, they don't do any thread counting before thread 14 reports itself to have started.  With your current code, thread number 14 both sets `has_T14_started` and checks `release_T14` in the same critical region.  `release_T14` will therefore remain 0 until after `has_T14_started` is set nonzero (see above), so the answer to your question

> How many times is thread 14 going to repeat that while loop where it
>   waits on the condition variable?

is ***none***.  Thread 14 will never wait, because the (incorrect) condition for it to proceed is guaranteed to be satisfied the very first time thread 14 tests it.

Furthermore, threads other than #14 read shared variable `has_T14_started` outside the protection of the mutex.  Thread 14 modifies that shared variable, so the read has undefined behavior.  I suppose your idea is to avoid locking the mutex if thread 14 has already been released, but that's a lost cause, because you need to consult shared variables to determine whether thread 14 has been (or should have been) released, and you can do that safely only with proper synchronization via the mutex.

Suggested corrections:

1. Get rid of variables `release_T14` and `has_T14_started` altogether.  You don't need either one, and they just confuse and complicate things.  Get rid of the `if(T14_has_started)` statement, and instead execute its body unconditionally.
2. Combine the two critical regions into one slightly wider one by locking the mutex immediately before `if (s->i == 14){` and unlocking it immediately after the associated `else` block. (Remove the locks and unlocks inside that region.)
3. Change the condition for thread 14 to wait to

   ```
   while (thread_count < 5)
   ```
4. If you mean to keep a thread count for more purposes than just determining when thread 14 can proceed, then probably you want to move the `thread_count++;` statement outside the `else` block to just after the (repositioned) `pthread_mutex_lock()` call, so that thread 14 increments it too.  You may then need to adjust the `while` condition slightly, as well.